# Add Field Identifier to a newly added iceberg column

Tags: apache-spark-sql, apache-iceberg

Is it possible to add a new column with user-defined field ID to an existing iceberg table? If yes, can anyone please share me spark-sql for the same.

Answer (score 0):

It's resolved, seems like it's not possible to add a user defined field ID to an existing or new col in iceberg table due to the fact how iceberg maintains the sort order, may be this feature can be added in future releases.